# Paypal buttons callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

In a ruby on rails app I want the ability for a person to donate to my paypal. However, I want to get a callback to know how much they donated. Is this possible with the default paypal 'buy' or 'donate' button, or will I have to use some sort of paypal api. Hopefully, there is some option besides the api.

Any info at all would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/).  When IPN is configured PayPal will POST transaction data to a listener script you have sitting on your server.  It'll handle payments, refunds, disputes, or pretty much any transaction that hits your PayPal account so you can automate things based on specific events in real-time.